# zsh refusing to accept new autocomplete script

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

I have a software project that I'm attempting to write zsh completions for. After installing a package that provided a number of pre-made completions, I found they were put here:

```
/usr/share/zsh/site-functions
```

So I wrote my completion script, and threw it in there too. ...and was frustrated by failure. I've tried the following:

1. Symlinking to the original script from the directory above.
2. Putting a copy of the script directly into the directory above.
3. Setting my login shell to zsh (instead of just switching to it from another shell)
4. (Probably) all permutations of `compinit` and `rehash`.
5. Dumbing-down my original script so that there's no way it could be wrong.
6. Changing the contents of another script. The changes worked, so the directory is correct and zsh is detecting completions scripts there.

Here is the dumbed-down script:

```
#compdef aura

_arguments -s \
  '-V[Version!]' \
  '-h[Helpppp]'
```

And the current contents of my .zshrc. I'm not normally a zsh user.

```
autoload -U compinit
compinit
zstyle ':completion:*' rehash true
```

Please and thank you for any insight you can give. What am I missing?

EDIT: Contents of /usr/share/zsh/site-functions is:

`_ack
_adb
_android
_attach
_aura
_baselayout
_bpython
_brew
_bundle
_cap
_choc
_coffee
_cower
_cpanm
_debuild
_dhcpcd
_ditz
_emulator
_eselect
_fab
_gas
_gcc-config
_geany
_gem
_genlop
_gentoolkit
_gentoo_packages
_git-flow
_github
_git-pulls
_git-wtf
_google
_gradle
_heroku
_jmeter
_jmeter-plugins
_jonas
_knife
_language_codes
_layman
_lein
_lunar
_lunchy
_manage.py
_mosh
_mvn
_node
_optirun
_pacman
_pactree
_pear
_perf
_periscope
_pgsql_utils
_pip
_pkcon
_play
_port
_portage
_portage_utils
_pygmentize
_redis-cli
_rvm
_sbt
_scala
_sdd
_setup.py
_showoff
_smartmontools
_srm
_ssh-copy-id
_subliminal
_symfony
_systemd
_teamocil
_thor
_tmuxinator
_vagrant
_virtualbox
_vnstat
_vpnc
_yaourt`

Comment: Is the script called `_aura`? What does `echo $_comps[aura]` show?

Comment: The script is called `_aura`, but `echo $_comps[aura]` returns an empty string.

Comment: What is the value of `fpath`? What is the content of `/usr/share/zsh/site-functions` (which by the way is not the proper place to install your script, `/usr/share` is reserved for the package manager, you should put your scripts under `/usr/local` or your home directory)? Are there `*.zwc` files around?

Comment: Thanks for helping. The contents of `fpath` are:  `/usr/share/zsh/site-functions` and all directories under `/usr/share/zsh/functions/`. There were too many to type out.

Comment: And it doesn't seem as if there are any `.zwc` files anywhere. I put the contents of `/usr/share/zsh/site-functions` in the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I think of that can go wrong.

The file containing the completion code must be in a directory listed in the `fpath` array. Ok. Note that you should not put your own files under `/usr/share`; zsh doesn't care, but your file could be deleted or overwritten by your operating system's package manager, and you're likely to forget to back it up, copy it to another machine, etc. You should put your own files under `/usr/local` if you want to make them available to all users on your system, and under your home directory if you just want them for your user. You can add a directory to `fpath` in your `.zshrc` (before calling `compinit`), e.g.

```
fpath=(~/lib/zsh $fpath)
```

The first line of the file must be `#compdef` followed by a space followed by one or more command names separated by spaces. Check that there aren't any stray characters there, in particular the file must have unix line endings (LF), not Windows line endings (CRLF — the stray CR might cause the command not to be picked up).

The `compinit` function creates a cache file the first time it runs, so as to be faster next time. This file is called `~/.zcompdump`. It contains the association between command names and completion functions (e.g. `aura _aura`), not the code of the functions. You may need to regenerate it sometimes. In particular, if you change the `#compdef` line in an existing file, `compinit` won't re-read the file. As long as you don't pass `-C` to `compinit`, it will pick up new files, but you must get the `#compdef` line right before the next time you start zsh. If you didn't, delete the cache file (`rm ~/.zcompdump`) and start zsh (or more precisely run `compinit`) again.

Comment: Zapped my old `.zcompdump` and now it works! Thanks a ton @Gilles.